# How can I let python print out the elements in a list in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I wrote this code to return every string in a list in the order of word length.

```
def sort_by_length(words: list[str]):
    return sorted(words, key=len)
print(sort_by_length(['this','is','a','test','for','sorting','by','length']))
```

and I get the output, which is

```
['a', 'is', 'by', 'for', 'this', 'test', 'length', 'sorting']
```

However, I want to change my code a bit so that if two or more strings has the same length, the code will return both the strings but in alphabetical order.

So like from the output that I get, I want it to be like:

```
['a', 'by', 'is', 'for', 'this', 'test', 'length', 'sorting']
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key function that returns a tuple.

```
def sort_by_length(words: list[str]):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```